# pyspark csv|parquet write failure java.io.IOException: File already exists

Tags: csv, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a job which writes into s3 after every iteration. I am using csv format (.gzip) for the same. The job fails after first iteration throwing an error that file exists even if I am overwriting the location. I tried appending as well but still getting the same issue.The code looks like below:

```
vdna_report_table_tmp.coalesce(2).write.save(path='s3://analyst-adhoc/elevate/tempData/VDNA_BRANDSURVEY_REPORT_TABLE_tmp/', format='csv', sep='|', compression='gzip', header=False, mode='overwrite')
```

and the error is something like below :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File already exists:s3://analyst-adhoc/elevate/tempData/VDNA_BRANDSURVEY_REPORT_TABLE_tmp/part-r-00001-69d1e948-c609-42b7-962e-451a23bbd3b3.csv.gz
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.create(S3NativeFileSystem.java:613)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:915)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:896)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:793)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.create(EmrFileSystem.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CsvOutputWriter.<init>(CSVRelation.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVOutputWriterFactory.newInstance(CSVRelation.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.newOutputWriter(WriterContainer.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

I am using pyspark 2.0.0

I tried the writing everything in parquet as well. in short I am doing below steps.

1. read data from a location (lets say A)
2. get some more data from another (lets say B)
3. union A and B
4. Write at location A( I tried appending and overwriting both fails saying the file already exists)

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: I was trying to write something in csv,gzip format in s3 and got an error "LiveListenerBus has already stopped" and DAGScheduler was throwing error "Broken pipe (write failed)" . I dont get these issues if I use parquet format. Is spark csv module not very well tested with AWS s3.

Comment: Or maybe your files are too big to save. Gzipped csv is not a splittable format and usually uses more space than parquet. Have you increasing coalesce parameter?

Comment: @Mariusz thanks for replying. the file is not a big one actually.Also, I will edit the question to explain a bit details

Comment: @braj259 try mode overwrite.  ``vdna_report_table_tmp.coalesce(2).write.mode("overwrite").save(path='s3://analyst-adhoc/elevate/tempData/VDNA_BRANDSURVEY_REPORT_TABLE_tmp/', format='csv', sep='|', compression='gzip', header=False, mode='overwrite')``

Comment: I am getting the same error, but only in a `re-attempted` task - first attempt fails with OOM, and then all following attempts fail with `File already exists`. Still looking for the problem